worksheet open event, using UserInterfaceOnly to protect all sheets - not working
I want to have all worksheets protected, but allow VBA to make changes
I usually have no problem accomplishing that, but this time I also want to allow the user to edit images
The end result is that the sheets are not protected
In the open worksheet event, I have the following code:
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet

For Each wsSheet In Worksheets
    wsSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Next

This works fine if I leave out the DrawingObjects:=False part - but as the code is, the sheets are unprotected
What I am doing wrong please?

The button for sheet protection on the ribbon displays as if the sheets are protected

Version 2409 (build 18025.20160)

Try
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet

For Each wsSheet In Worksheets
wsSheet.Unprotect
    wsSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Next


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
